# TypeError: counters.indexOf is not a function in React list

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, web-frontend

I have a list in state of a class and when a click event is called I need to get the selected component from the list. here is my code

```
class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 0 },
      { id: 2, value: 2 },
      { id: 3, value: 2 },
      { id: 4, value: 3 }
    ]
  };

  handleIncrement = counter => {
    const counters = { ...this.state.counters };
    console.log(counter); //this returns when this triggerrd {id: 2, value: 2}
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
};
```

Comment: `{ ...this.state.counters }` typo, you're spreading into an object, not into an array (only arrays have an `indexOf` method)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have changed it to `[...this.state.counters];` now the error is gone. I get your point. Thank you. but I still get the index as -1 do you have a catch about this?

Comment: You can not use indexOf to match an object. You should be using find()

Comment: @epascarello I'm expecting to get the index of this object in the array. find() will be useful to find the object though.

Comment: well indexOf is not going to work. So if you need to find the index, than you need to loop and look for a match.

Comment: @epascarello that is a helpful comment. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are copying the values of an array into an object.

```
const counters = [...this.state.counters]
```

Comment: Hi @paruchuri-p this code fixed giving the error so according to the scope of the question I will mark this as the answer. but I still have a problem with index. it gives me -1.